# react native deep links android 12

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, android-12

React native deep links keep failing on android version 12, anybody has some help?
On older versions it works fine, so the config must be fine and I checked probably 100 times the react native documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android 12 requires the developer to verify the domain to be able to use the links. For ios it is required to upload a json into a

> .well-known

folder on your webhosting to verify the domain is really yours. Since Android 12 you have to do the same for Android.

You create a file called assetlinks.json and upload it to the same folder as the ios file.

```
 [{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "<Your App’s package name>",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["<Your App’s SHA256 finger print>"]
  }
}]
```

The fingerprint can get created via Android Studio:

> /tools/App Links Assistant

There you can also verify that it worked, later of course also within the application.